# D3 html div tooltip on pie chart

Tags: html, d3.js

I'm having troubles displaying the tooltip on a pie chart. It must be something with the 'path'. Inspecting the element shows the div but it doesn't seem to be visible at all

```
      var path = svg.selectAll('path')
      .data(pie(dataset))
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr('fill', function(d, i) { 
        return color(d.data.label);
      })
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          d3.select("#tooltip")
              .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
              .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
              .style("opacity", 1)
              .select("#value")
              .text(d.value);
      })
          .on("mouseout", function () {
          // Hide the tooltip
          d3.select("#tooltip")
              .style("opacity", 0);
      });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jenrocodes/q60kqhbx/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is that in the html, when you declared the tooltip you left the `hidden` attribute:

```
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
```

And you never removed it on mousover, so the tooltip was still hidden, even with an opacity of 1.

I solved you issue by setting the opacity to 0 on init:

```
<div id="tooltip" style="opacity:0">
```

In order to solve this problem, I looked at the chrome console (the elements tab) and saw that all attributes of the tooltip were correctly updated except for the `hidden` one.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q60kqhbx/2/)

Comment: ugh! so that's how it was. sorry for the noob question, and thank you!

Comment: No worries, I figured you wouldn't feel good about the answer. However I found the way you placed the html tooltip on top of the svg quite elegant :-)